# Из модального окна: закрыть окно и вызвать метод другого окна

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, события, action

.Net 4.5.2, C#, WinForms, обычное оконное приложение Windows.
Есть основное окно в своём потоке. Из этого окна открывается модальное окно в своём потоке.
В модальном окне есть кнопка, по которой надо вызвать метод, вызываемый из меню основного окна (это не ОК, не CANCEL). При нажатии этой кнопки надо сразу закрыть модальное окно.
Т.е. метод надо бы вызывать как-то асинхронно. Просто отправить "команду" на выполнение, закрыть модальное окно и забыть обо всём.

Вариант сделать это из основного окна, отслеживая так или иначе нажатие нужной кнопки, не предлагать - это просто.
Можно ли сделать это именно так, как я это описал? Т.е. запустить как-то "команду" на выполнение и спокойно закрыть модальное окно?

Comment: Вам не должно такого хотеться. Окно должно отправить команду/сигнал основной программе и закрыться, а уж программа пускай запускает длинные операции.

Comment: видимо, вы не очень поняли вопрос. ну да ладно. вы предлагаете сначала что-то вызвать в объекте Application?

Comment: Не обязательно Application, любой объект, который должен у вас реализовывать нужную логику. Почему модальное окно в отдельном потоке?

Comment: Иначе говоря, вы хотите прибить родителя (модальное окно) и оставить thread сиротой? Так делать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь спрятать родительское окно , а потом уже его закрыть . Но лучше используй эвенты . Пусть твое модальное окно выбрассывает эвент , предварительно подпиши на него метод из главного окна . не забудь модификатор public